# Can .NET extensions not be accessed via reflections?

Tags: .net, xna, lua, extension-methods

I've created an XNA application that utilizes LuaInterface (via Lua) to control many aspects of the application itself.

I added an extension to an XNA class (specifically the `KeyboardState` object).  The problem is, if I call the extended function with Lua, I get an error:  ***Attempt to call field 'KeyDown' (a userdata value***.

Here is my Lua script:

```
Game.Updated:Add(function(t)
    if Players.LocalPlayer.Controller.KeyboardState:KeyDown(KeyboardKey.W) then
        print("W key down")
    end
end)
```

And here is my module extending the class:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Module XNAExtensions
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function KeyDown(ByVal this As Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.KeyboardState, ByVal e As Integer) As Boolean
        Return this.IsKeyDown(e)
    End Function
End Module
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extension methods are a function of the *compiler*, not the framework.  In order to call this from Lua, you will need to call your XNAExtensions module directly as a static method.  Lua doesn't understand extension methods.

```
XNAExtensions:KeyDown(Players.LocalPlayer.Controller.KeyboardState, KeyboardKey.W)
```

Comment: Well this certainly is a downer.  Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 2):

Extension methods aren't an actual extension of the class, like subclassing is.  It's something that's understood by the C# and VB compiler when parsing the source files but the compiled bytecode still looks like it came from `XNAExtensions.KeyDown(keyboardState, e)`

To call it from your Lua script you'll have to access the method from the static class rather than as an extension method.